# Singularity could not open image

Tags: image, singularity-container, nextflow, samtools

I ran my workflow with nextflow using singularity, for my first process there are no problems, but the second one gives me this error:
`could not open image /staphb/samtools:1.15.img: failed to retrieve path for /staphb/samtools:1.15.img: lstat /staphb: no such file or directory`

This is part of my nextflow.config file:

```
singularity {
        autoMounts = true
        runOptions = "--bind ${params.bind_path}"
}


singularity.enabled = true

process {
        errorStrategy = "ignore"
        withName:MAP { container = "winnowmap:2.03--h43eeafb_2" }
        withName:SAMTOOLS { container = "/work/my_singularity_container/staphb-samtools-1.15.img" }
     
}


dag { enabled = true }
report { enabled = true }
timeline { enabled = true }
trace { enabled = true }
```

First I tried changing the container name in my config like this:

`withName:SAMTOOLS { container = "staphb/samtools:1.15" }`

but it kept giving the same error, so I tried downloading another image, but it still gave me the error:

`could not open image /staphb/samtools:1.15.img: failed to retrieve path for /staphb/samtools:1.15.img: lstat /staphb: no such file or directory`, even if I changed the container in my nextflow.config:

```
process {
        errorStrategy = "ignore"
        withName:MAP { container = "winnowmap:2.03--h43eeafb_2" }
        withName:SAMTOOLS { container = "samtools_1.17:hd87286a_1" }
```

I checked the images and they all work

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of my process and workflow and it worked.